# Use response of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm new in JS and I'm trying to create a function that check something before submit a form.
On  html I have:

```
<form name="loginform" method="post" onsubmit="return foo()" action="adminlogin.php"> ... </form>
```

The function foo() is:

```
foo(){
  if(..){
  return false;
  }
  else{
        var url = "credenziali.php";
        var params = "name="+username+"&password="+password;
        var http_r = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http_r.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                //something
            }
        };
        http_r.open("GET", url+"?name="+username+"&pass="+password, true);
        http_r.send();
        // here I want to return false or true dependence of responseText
    }
```

the comment in the function is where I want use the what the request returns.
How can I do?

Comment: You can't.  `foo()` finishes before the ajax request returns a response.  Whatever code is hoping for a return value needs to be executed in the callback (where you have `//something`)

Answer (score 0):

Try insert this before http_r.send() with your return inside.

```js
http_r.onload = function() {
  if (http_r.status >= 200 && http_r.status < 400) {
    // Success!
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
  }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Use JQuery AJAX instead...http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ it's much more concise.